# Show login/signup while doing payment with paypal

Tags: paypal

I'm using PayPal Website Payments Standard built in php. Whenever the user lands on PayPal with the variables I sent, it shows a PayPal Login form and at the bottom it shows "Don't have a PayPal account? Use your credit card or bank account (where available)."  I want it to default to always ask for sign up and proceed

Answer (score 0):

Add variable landing_page=billing in PHP code, then the default page is pay with credit card.

```html
<input type="hidden" name="landing_page" value="billing">
```